# trait AppearsOnTable<schema::cost_items::table> is not implement for ‘f64’

Tags: postgresql, rust, actix-web, rust-diesel

I am experimenting Rust using a typical rest api service with database backend use case to learn the programming language and its libraries. I started with using actix-web for rest api and routes, and diesel for ORM. In the process, I run into an issue during compilation where I defined numeric data type in the database table, and used diesel ORM to map the table to object. One of the compilation errors I am getting is “trait AppearsOnTableschema::cost_items::table is not implement for ‘f64’”. I read different documentations, but they suggested that database Numeric data type maps to f64 Rust primitive type. I know I still have a lot to learn, I have already spent two days reading,  searching and experimenting but that didn’t seem to help to make any progress so I need some  help. Can anyone kindly provide some pointers to me how I may resolve this compilation issue? Thanks in advance.

Simple table in database:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public.cost_items (
    id bigserial NOT NULL,
    "name" varchar(64) NOT NULL,
    price numeric NOT NULL,
    notes text NULL,
    CONSTRAINT cost_items_pk PRIMARY KEY (id),
    CONSTRAINT cost_items_un UNIQUE ("name")
);
```

Rust class (both has compilation errors at the price line):

```
#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, AsChangeset, Insertable)]
#[diesel(table_name = cost_items)]
pub struct CostItem {
    pub name: String,
    pub price: f64,
    pub notes: String,
}

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, Queryable, Insertable, ToSchema)]
#[diesel(table_name = cost_items)]
pub struct CostItems {
    pub id: i64,
    pub name: String,
    pub price: f64,
    pub notes: String,
}
```

Schema generated by diesel:

```
diesel::table! {
    cost_items (id) {
        id -> Int8,
        name -> Varchar,
        price -> Numeric,
        notes -> Nullable<Text>,
    }
}
```

I am using PostgreSQL 13.

I tried changing the native types to BigDecimal and still have the similar compilation error.

**EDIT**:
I figured out what the problem is. Basically, I need to wrap the field with Option<> for database table's field that allows NULL.

```
pub struct CostItems {
    pub id: i64,
    pub name: String,
    pub price: f64,
    pub notes: String,
```

}

Need to be

```
pub struct CostItems {
    pub id: i64,
    pub name: String,
    pub price: f64,
    pub notes: Option<String>,
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the Float8 type for price

```rust
diesel::table! {
    cost_items (id) {
        id -> Int8,
        name -> Varchar,
        price -> Float8,
    }
}
```

Now the create table query would change to

```sql
price DOUBLE PRECISION
```

Diesel has a mapping of which rust types to use for Postgres and other supported databases, which can be found here
Postgres sql ->  https://github.com/diesel-rs/diesel/blob/master/diesel_cli/tests/generate_migrations/diff_add_table_all_the_types/postgres/up.sql/expected.snap

Generated schema -> https://github.com/diesel-rs/diesel/blob/master/diesel_cli/tests/generate_migrations/diff_add_table_all_the_types/postgres/schema.rs

Comment: Thank you Narayan. I tried that and got the following compilation error.

let cost_items = cost_items::table.load::<CostItems>(&mut conn)?;
     |                                            ----              ^^^^^^^^^ the trait `load_dsl::private::CompatibleType<cost_items::model::CostItems, Pg>` is not implemented for `(BigInt, diesel::sql_types::Text, diesel::sql_types::Double, diesel::sql_types::Nullable<diesel::sql_types::Text>)`
     |                                            |
     |                                            required by a bound introduced by this call

Comment: I would also like to point out that that both the tables should have same types and same number of columns, this seems to be caused because your schema has 4 columns whereas your struct definition seems to have only 3 columns

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo on my part of the posting. Thanks for pointing that out though, Narayan.

Comment: Just want to clarify that the schema.rs was generated by diesel migration run.

Comment: I was trying other thing out while waiting for suggestion. Thank you Narayan anyway for pointing it out.

Comment: error[E0277]: the trait bound `(BigInt, diesel::sql_types::Text, diesel::sql_types::Double, diesel::sql_types::Nullable<diesel::sql_types::Text>):

Comment: load_dsl::private::CompatibleType<cost_items::model::CostItems, Pg>` is not satisfied
    --> src/cost_items/model.rs:32:62
     |

Comment: 32   |         let cost_items = cost_items::table.load::<CostItems>(&mut conn)?;
     |                                            ----              ^^^^^^^^^ the trait `load_dsl::private::CompatibleType<cost_items::model::CostItems, Pg>` is not implemented for `(BigInt, diesel::sql_types::Text, diesel::sql_types::Double, diesel::sql_types::Nullable<diesel::sql_types::Text>)`
     |                                            |
     |                                            required by a bound introduced by this call

Comment: Just try again... same error.

Comment: Can you share the struct definition and the schema generated by diesel? You can hop on to my discord server where we can discuss in detail if you are facing more issues https://discord.gg/hqEgXPvv

Comment: Hi Narayan, here is the repo in github for my experimenting with Rust.

https://github.com/cchee/rust-tryout

Comment: Finally figure out what the problem is... 
In my table. one of the column is Nullable, but in my struct, I forgot to wrap that field in Option<>. Once I do that, everything compiles fine.